# discord.js change nickname of server owner

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am currently developing a discord.js bot for my server, and it has an integrated "Level System" that works with nicknames.
So that means the bot sets the nickname of all users to their display name and simply adds the level they are at the end of it:

```
    bot.guilds.get("693909572167139338").members.forEach((member) => {
         if(member.user.bot) return;
         const entity = new LevelEntity(member);
         bot.levelEntities.set(member, entity);
    });

    bot.levelEntities.forEach((entity) => {
         if(entity.getLevelHolder().displayName.includes("Lv. ")) return;
         if(entity.getLevelHolder().displayName.length >= 32) return;
         entity.getLevelHolder().setNickname(entity.getLevelHolder().displayName + " " + 
         entity.getLevel());
         console.log(`[${moment().format('DD/MM/YY, h:mm a')}]`.italic.yellow + ` LEVELENTITY `.cyan 
         + `Set Level Nick for `.green + `${entity.getLevelHolder().user.username}`.grey);
    });
```

The point is: The bot cannot change my nickname because Im the owner.
My Question: How can I achieve, that the bot can change my nickname or is it even possible?

Greetings, 
Linus E.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible due to Discord restrictions, a bot can't outrank the owner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, this cannot be done due to discord restrictions.

Comment: Thats to bad, but thatnks for your respons!